# Agora.io Flexible Classroom does not let student draw on whiteboard

Tags: agora.io

I am using the default [integration](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-class/product_agora_class) and when the student joins he doesn't have access to the drawing tools only the teacher has, by the docs it says that both should have access. Did anyone face this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using small classroom you need to give access to the student to the whiteboard for them to be able to access it. If you're using the one-to-one classroom both users should be able to draw on the whiteboard, in which case I'd double check the integration or contact support.